# Prompting user to select an option in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I want to run a macro, but I would like the macro to, when it is run, prompt the user with something like "Are you sure that XYZ?" and have the prompt have two buttons, "Yes" which when clicked on proceeds to run the rest of the macro's actual function and "No" which kills the macro and allows user to first check XYZ before initiating the macro. I know I can prompt the user to input a value, but how do I get them to have only two buttons to select in the prompt?

Comment: @ScottCraner - that is vb.net code, which may throw the OP given the differences in syntax

Comment: @ScottHoltzman So it was.  My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a standard `MsgBox` prompt, and only call on your procedure if the response is "Yes".

Here is an example, basically you will "run" the procedure that does the validation (Yes/No), and if the response is yes, then this procedure runs *your* other macro.

```
Sub DoXYZ()
Dim mb as Long

mb = MsgBox("Are you sure that XYZ?", vbYesNo)

If mb = vbYes Then
    Call "YourOtherMacro" '## MODIFY WITH YOUR PROCEDURE'S NAME
End If

'Note: a response of vbNo will do nothing

End Sub
```